# Power BI: Conditional Formating Data bars for Matrix Visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a matrix in the following format The total sales and percentage sales below each other:

[image]

This is why I have created a table with data like this:

| Salesperson | Country | Sales | Product | Format |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | USA | 0.45 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| John | Canada | 0.34 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| John | Italy | 0.67 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| Gina | USA | 0.43 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| Gina | Canada | 0.56 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| Gina | Italy | 0.21 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| Mary | USA | 0.12 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| Mary | Canada | 0.53 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| Mary | Italy | 0.12 | Mountain Bike | Percentage |
| John | USA | 0.22 | City Bike | Percentage |
| John | Canada | 0.32 | City Bike | Percentage |
| John | Italy | 0.12 | City Bike | Percentage |
| Gina | USA | 0.11 | City Bike | Percentage |
| Gina | Canada | 0.02 | City Bike | Percentage |
| Gina | Italy | 0.32 | City Bike | Percentage |
| Mary | USA | 0.11 | City Bike | Percentage |
| Mary | Canada | 0.21 | City Bike | Percentage |
| Mary | Italy | 0.32 | City Bike | Percentage |
| John | USA | 2250 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| John | USA | 1700 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| John | USA | 3350 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| Gina | USA | 2150 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| Gina | Canada | 2800 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| Gina | Italy | 1050 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| Mary | USA | 600 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| Mary | Canada | 2650 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| Mary | Italy | 600 | Mountain Bike | Total |
| John | USA | 1100 | City Bike | Total |
| John | USA | 1600 | City Bike | Total |
| John | USA | 600 | City Bike | Total |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Under Sales column is the total amount and percentage amount of sale and the matrix will filter after the Format column. But since I need to change the format of the percentage to percent, because it's in decimal format, I have created a measure for sales like this:

```
Sales_all = 
VAR variable = SUM ( 'Table'[Sales])
RETURN
SWITCH (
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Format]),
"Total", FORMAT ( variable, "General Number" ),
"Percentage", FORMAT ( variable, "Percent" ))
```

I have two questions. I would like to create a data bar conditional formatting for Percentage:

1. Is it possible to use different values for max and min of the data bar for each country. Currently when I choose data bars, I can only enter values for the whole column of Sales, disregarding the Countries (Canada, Italy, USA). For example I would like to enter a max value for Canada as 60% and max value for Italy as 25%. If I use the Sales column directly, not as measure, I can only choose one max value for the whole Sales column. The bar for the percentage should be full at 60% for Canada and full at 25% for Italy.
2. Since I have used a measure to change the format of the values in Sales column based on the Format column, I can't choose data bar under conditional formatting anymore? Why is this the case and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep each post to a single question. Please don't paste data as images and keep the sample data as copiable text.

I don't understand question 1 so you will need to elaborate (ideally in a brand new question with copiable sample data). The reason for question 2 is that FORMAT() returns text and so is no longer a number and can't produce a data bar. Either keep the measure as a number or change the display formatting using calculation groups.

**EDIT**

You need to reshape your data. In PQ, pivot Format column with value of Sales as follows:

[image]

You end up with this (missing data because your sample wasn't complete)

[image]

Create a matrix as follows:

[image]

Highlight the column or measure for percentage and in the ribbon select percent for the format. This keeps the underlying value as a number but changes the display only.

[image]

On the matrix, ensure you have the following option.

[image]

You should now have the following:

[image]

You can now add data bars to percentage column.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alright, I will update the post with the data. Regarding Q1: For Matrix I put the Sales Column into the Value field. For conditional formatting I right click and choose data bars. But I can only enter a user defined value for max and min for the whole Sales Column. Is it possible to enter different max values based on Country? Regarding Q2: Any idea how I can change it to be useable with data bars?

Comment: I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Thanks, thought about it too but was left with the question regarding different max values for data bars based on the country. I will create a separat question for that.